# Thumbnail hides after position:relative

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a screen where I am using a `Thumbnail` and a `UserInfoContainer`, which is a PanGestureHandler(React native animation element that scrolls up). I want that even when I scroll up my `UserInfoContainer` container, the Thumbnail should stay on top of it at the same position.

```
export const Screen: React.FunctionComponent = () => {

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaViewContainer}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.iconsContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.cross}>
          <Thumbnail
            source={{
              uri:
                'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/very-basic-android-l-lollipop-icon-pack/24/close-512.png',
            }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <HamburgerIcon style={styles.hamburgerIcon}/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.infoContainer}>
          <UserInfoContainer />
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  safeAreaViewContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#323443',
    flex: 1,
  },
  iconsContainer:{
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  cross: {
    paddingTop: moderateScale(30),
    paddingLeft: moderateScale(20),
    zIndex: 100,
  },
  infoContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },

});
```

I have added a zIndex but now when I add `position: 'absolute'`, my thumbnail just disappears. This has worked with another FontAwesomeIcon but its not working here in case of my Thumbnail. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: When using `position: 'absolute'` you need to position the element with 'top', 'bottom', 'right' and 'left' styles.

Also, it'll no longer be relative so you can move the code block down below the other elements, meaning it will always render on top, no need for zIndex.

Comment: In react native stylesheets, we cant assign fixed to position. Just "absolute" | "relative" | undefined

Comment: Oh yes sorry, you're right, in which case you should use 'absolute'

Comment: Sorry, my initial qs was that it disappears when I add absolute. I wrote relative by mistake. Tho it disappears on both.

Comment: You may need to position it, try adding ```{top: 0, right: 0}```  for example, does it appear at the top right?